# Sagepay Direct on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, payment-gateway, opayo

I can't seem to be able to whitelist the correct IP ranges for use with Sagepay direct payment module.

I keep getting invalid response 4020 : Information received from an Invalid IP address.

The instance is a non VPC instance and it is able to talk outbound on the correct port (hence getting any response at all). It has a public IP address attached to it and I have whitelisted that in the sagepay backend.

The entry looks something like this

054.217.010.211 - 255.255.255.000

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

4020 error - happens with a Server or Direct integration. Fixed IP recommended. If you've added the IP address and subnet mask to cover the range to MySagePay (Sage Pays admin portal) and still getting error, means we're not recognising the IP your posting from as the IP you have given.

Invalid Transactions within MySagePay, you should be able to see the IP we're recognising that you're posting from. Then add that IP to MySagePay.

Sage Pay may need to check that our internal IPs are registered against your account.

Sage Pay can add the IP ranges for you to your Sage Pay account if needed so you can check it resolves.